# Implementing a queue with parallel processing - different approaches

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue

I want to discuses different approaches for parallel `queue` processing.

**Implementation 1, using a `BlockingCollection` and `Task.Parallel`:**

```
private BlockingCollection<Item> _collection = new BlockingCollection<Item>();

Void StartQueue()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(async (s) =>
    {
        var partitioner = Partitioner.Create(_collection.GetConsumingEnumerable(token), EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);
        Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, parallelOptions, async item =>
         {
             ..process(item);
         });
    }, new System.Threading.CancellationToken(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}

void EnqueItem(Item item)
{
    _collection.Add(item);
}
```

Here I read that `BlockingCollection` and `Task.Parallel` are both using locks which makes them not to work too well together.

**Implementation 2, using a `ConcurrentQueue` and `Task.Parallel`:**

```
private ConcurrentQueue<Item> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Item>();

Void StartQueue()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(async (x) =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var partitioner = Partitioner.Create(_queue, EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);
            Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, parallelOptions, async item =>
            {
                 ..process(item);
            })
            Task.Delay(TIMEOUT_MS);
        }
    ;
    }, new System.Threading.CancellationToken(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}

void EnqueItem(Item item)
{
    _queue.Enqueue(item);
}
```

**Implementation 3, using `BlockingCollection` and `SemaphoreSlim`:**

```
private BlockingCollection<Item> _collection = new BlockingCollection<Item>();
private SemaphoreSlim m_AvailableDispatchHandlersSempahore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxThreads);;
private int m_AvailableScanThreads = maxThreads;

Void StartQueue()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(async s =>
    {
        try
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested && _collection.Count > 0)
                {
                    await m_AvailableDispatchHandlersSempahore.WaitAsync(token);
                    Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_AvailableScanThreads);

                    Item item = null;
                    bool didSucceedTakeData = _collection.TryTake(out item);
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (didSucceedTakeData)
                            {
                                Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                {
                                    proceesItem(item);
                                }, token);


                                bool didFinishInTime = task.Wait(Constants.Milliseconds.SECOND * timeout);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            s_Logger.Error($"....", ex);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            m_AvailableDispatchHandlersSempahore.Release();
                            Interlocked.Increment(ref m_AvailableScanThreads);
                        }
                    }, token);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(Constants.Milliseconds.SECOND * 30);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            s_Logger.Error("....", ex);
        }

    }, token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}

void EnqueItem(Item item)
{
    _collection.Add(item);
}
```

What do you think of this implementations, and is there a better implementation for the task.

Comment: Hi, sorry but this question is not suited for StackOverflow. On this forum it will be closed either as too broad or oppinion based. You should may be migrate it to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) Or may be you can rephrase it as a specific programming problem. Describe where you got stuck, what you expect to happen and so on

Comment: If you look at the [asking-help-page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) it states: "If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. "

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel (particularly one involving threading)?  Use _TPL DataFlow_

Comment: @Mong Zhu yea I understand, but it does have some value for programmers who want to see one post summarizing the topic

Comment: @MickyD I will take a look and update

Comment: @MongZhu As long as no context is provided, this question has no place whatsoever on Code Review. Please take a look at their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Mast seems legit. At: omriman12 Then either forget my suggestion to migrate the question or include a valid context.

Comment: You should read this https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html and using Thread.Sleep is most time bad.